# Code snippet explaination, function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, syntax

I'm a beginner Java dev and need to use JS script in my app, so please take it easy on me. I found a code in Javascript and I'm trying to understand it.

The code snippet:

```
window.NETWORK_STAT_MAP = new Map(networkStat[symbol.toLowerCase()]);

NETWORK_STAT_MAP.forEach(function(url, host, map) {
$.getJSON(url + '/stats', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

- First of all, `NETWORK_STAT_MAP` is a JS map.
- `networkStat` is an iterable.
- Next we have a `function(url, host, map)` call on each of map's items. Are function parameters variables in the map's items? Or should they be declared somewhere else in the .js file?
- Is it possible to convert a JSON file into such map?

Comment: Note that Java and Javascript are two **very** different things. I edited your question for clarity.

Comment: No mistake there, I'm a Java dev and need to use Javascript. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should have a look at MDN :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

> The forEach method executes the provided callback once for each key of the map which actually exist. It is not invoked for keys which have been deleted. However, it is executed for values which are present but have the value undefined.
>
> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element key
> - the Map object being traversed

for JSON, if you are searching for `forEach` yes, it is native.
For instance

```
const JSON = {
   data: [1, 2, 3]
}
JSON.data.forEach(/*...*/)
```